# Websphere MQ configuration - Environment variables (MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR)

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, ibm-mq

We have an application that has been working fine on a Windows XP box, and a Windows Server 2008 server (64 bit).

It connects to an IBM iSeries/AS400 Message Queue.

Now I need to upgrade the code and deploy it on a new Win7 64 bit machine.

So I ran the setup for Websphere MQ (it's in a folder 'mqc6_6.0.2.6_win\Windows') and it then ran the Prepare Websphere MQ Wizard which also finished successfully.

But when I run my application I get the error

```
MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR
```

As I say, this application runs fine on other machines including a 64 bit machine with the same Message Queue, so what am I missing?

Is there something else I need to do for the setup?

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: What does the error log say? Are you using client connections or local bindings? If client, are you using CCDT?

Comment: I will check when I get back into the office, and post the error messages, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was annoyingly and gratifyingly simple...

We need to specify the MQSERVER in an environment variable, which I had missed.

So once I set **MQSERVER=SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN/TCP/BOCTEST** it worked fine.

There is more information about this [here (IBM)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009320_.htm)